# Obtaining paths from .tfrecords file in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tfrecord

Is it possible to get the paths of records (data items) from .tfrecord file? For example, in order to get the total number of records, we can use `tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator` .

**For example**
If I have 100 raw images and I converted them to .tfrecords format. Now I can load them into my tensorflow model to access them. Is there a way I can access the location of the disk (paths) of these images using .tfrecords?

Comment: Note [`tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/tf_record_iterator) is deprecated, and [`tf.data.TFRecordDataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TFRecordDataset) is the recommended way of accessing TFRecord data. I don't really understand your question though, I'm not sure what paths you want to get. Maybe you could give some example.

Comment: @jdehesa Please see my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a tfrecord file from a batch of images, It means that the data from these images is stored in the tfrecord file in bytes format. You can store the path of the original image to the tfrecord file e.g.:

```
def image_example(image_string, label, path):

    feature = {
        'label': _int64_feature(label),
        'image_raw': _bytes_feature(image_string),
        'path': _bytes_feature(path),
    }

    return tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
```